# Special case of mixed client and server side rendering | What would this be called?

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

#### Case Study

Consider the following scenerio:

- I have a Node-Express server
- The server renders a new `.html` file for every page and sends it to the client
- Within each `.html` file:

  - there is some dynamic content filled in with `EJS` (such as the user's name in the navigation bar),
  - and part of the page (inside a `<div id='app'></div>`) is a React App (for instance, a table view with filters).
  - `ReactJS`, `ReactDOM`, and my React code is imported using `<script src="___.js">` tags
- Every time the client clicks on a link to go to another page, the server handles the routing and generates a new `.html` file that has

  - some dynamic content (e.g. user name in navbar)
  - A div containing a new React App, with the react code imported in `script` tags

#### Question

My question is Am I right to say that when it comes to Routing, this application uses "Server-Side Routing" and as for Rendering, a mixture of Client and Server-Side Routing?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your questions #2 and (perhaps) #3:

I would distinguish between *static content*, which is the same for all users of an app, and *dynamic content*, which depends on the user and can also change over time.

Server-side rendering is when the server produces HTML page that contain dynamic content. Such pages cannot be cached (at least not in a public cache, and even a private cache would have to be invalidated as the content changes over time). A further consequence of server-side rendering is that the whole HTML page must be reloaded when the dynamic content changes.

An alternative approach is a static (cacheable) HTML page that loads and renders all dynamic content with Javascript code ([AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))). This leads to pages that build up over time, as the dynamic content is loaded, and the "time to visual completeness" can become an issue.

Your approach sounds like a compromise where HTML pages contain some dynamic content, whereas other parts of the dynamic content (that change more frequently, I assume) are handled with AJAX methods.

Comment: Thank you. You got the approach right in your last paragraph, and that is my question. Will this approach be called "a mix of client and server-side rendering"? Because part of the content is dynamically rendered by the server, and part of it by react on the client side.

Comment: Don't know if there is a special name for that approach.